# How can I send a custom Delivery Status Notification over Postfix SMTP server?

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dsn

I'm trying to send out the following Mime message through my mail SMTP server which is Postfix.

```
From: Webmaster <webmaster@ourdomain.com>
Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2021 23:50:56 +0100
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
Message-Id: <GII2AYZOWCU4.AXDWNKVKJ4XD3@ourdomain.com>
To: First Last <someone@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; boundary="=-HnKieASbitf0LQ3XjF16Mw==";
    report-type=delivery-status

--=-HnKieASbitf0LQ3XjF16Mw==
Content-Type: text/plain

Attachment not allowed
--=-HnKieASbitf0LQ3XjF16Mw==
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns;mail.ourdomain.com

Final-Recipient: rfc822;user@ourdomain.com
Action: failed
Status: 550 5.7.1


--=-HnKieASbitf0LQ3XjF16Mw==--
```

The problem I'm having is that Postfix sends the message as a regular massage with the related parts stripped.

Is it not possible to send a custom DSN message manually?